# Integrating Mizu Webphone Library API into React JS Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sip

I am currently working on a React JS project and have integrated the Mizu webphone library by placing the Webphone folder in my public directory. I've utilized the `softphone.HTML` file within my React component through the `<iframe>` tag. However, I am now seeking guidance on utilizing the Mizu Webphone library's API directly in my React project from scratch.

Could someone provide insights or best practices on how to effectively integrate the Mizu Webphone library's API within a React JS application? Any advice on initializing the API and handling its functionalities in a React context would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!